# Transition between viewController only in code

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I want to click on a button to make a transition between 2 scenes.

I have a custom button :

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let image = UIImage(named: "playButton.png") as UIImage

    button   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
    button.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.width/2, self.view.frame.height/2)

    button.addTarget(self, action: "transition:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    button .setBackgroundImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    self.view.addSubview(button)

}
```

My transition function

```
func transition(sender:UIButton!)
{
    println("Button tapped")

    let sec: GameViewController = GameViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    self.presentViewController(sec, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I have this error : "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbd71ca7270"

I don't know what do I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your button is calling a method that doesn't exist.  See this line:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Since your `transition:` method runs the transition, you should add that as the target action.

```
button.addTarget(self, action: "transition:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: It was already corrected in my code (actually I edited the method name directly in the post but I forgot to change the target action. It still doesn't work with this correction.

Answer (score 0):

```
func transition(sender:UIButton!)
{
    let VC1 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameViewController")
    self.presentViewController(VC1, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In your Storyboard give storyboard ID to your GameViewController. This must work.